# Point "made by" intersections?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

There are lines and when they intersect, there is a point. I am not sure if "make" is the correct here:

> With 4 points **made** by interesections of both vertical and horizontal
>   lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

> With 4 *intersection points* of vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: Thanks. Would "made" be really wrong?

Comment: @SilkySand: I am not sure. It doesn't sound right to me. *created* sounds better, although I would still go with the option suggested in the answer. Warning: I am a non-native speaker.

Comment: *Created* is what I'd use.

Comment: How about "... with 4 intersection points created by both vertical and horizontal lines"?

Answer (score 2):

The term **[define](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/define)** is frequently used to describe the factors that establish *points* (or lines, shapes, limits) in geometry

> to determine the boundary or extent of

You could say

> With 4 points *defined* by interesections of both vertical and horizontal lines.

I think this would sound better and be clearer than *made*.

Answer (score 0):

Why is ***at*** not enough? Is there a reason you **must** state that the lines are responsible for the creation of the points?

> … with 4 points **at** the intersection of the vertical and horizontal lines.

or even,

> … with 4 points **of** intersection of the vertical and horizontal lines.

And yes,

> … with 4 points **made/ created by/ at** the intersection of vertical and horizontal lines

The points are made/ created by the intersection, not by the lines *per se*.